# How to view contents from a E01 or dd file

Tags: file, vmware, computer-forensics

I created a .E01 file and a .dd file for my computer. I want to look into some of the parts of it (such as directories). I would like to be able to analyze what is on the E01 file, but I am not sure how. What are ways to be able to view these files? I'd assume I could do it with vmware or something similar, but I am unable to find guides on this online.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows system you can use the program [FTK Imager](https://accessdata.com/product-download/ftk-imager-version-4-5) and mount e01 or dd image files and display the contents.

On Linux systems xmount, mount etc is your friend